# How does model class default keyword works in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have set mapping for a column in my model class as

```
class Plan(Base):
    __tablename__ = "plans"
    `default_c = Column(Boolean, default=False)`
```

But when i am inserting data to this table using . below code. I am still getting `(exceptions.TypeError) Not a boolean value: ''` . I have `default_c` field empty in my dictionary. I was wondering if the `default` should have handled this.

```
conn.execute(Plan.__table__.insert(), Plan_dict)
```

Plan_dict is my list of dictionaries which I want to insert into plans table.

Comment: Please provide a definition for `Plan_dict`, or in other words produce a [mcve]. Does "empty in my dictionary" mean an empty string value, as it would seem?

Comment: Yes .. it is an empty string value

Answer (score 3):

According to [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.default) if you don't provide the column then it will populate the default value

> A scalar, Python callable, or ColumnElement expression representing the default value for this column, which will be invoked upon insert if this column is otherwise not specified in the VALUES clause of the insert. This is a shortcut to using ColumnDefault as a positional argument; see that class for full detail on the structure of the argument.

I feel that you are giving the `default_c` an empty value. Remove the `default_c` from your `Plan_dict` and give it a try.

Comment: I cannot .. Is there any way I can handle this with sqlalchemy itself?

Comment: Then you can have a check if `default_c` is empty and then update its value to "False" rather providing a default in Model itself.